# Ionic Build Fails

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have started working one existing project. And I have hardly few week experience in android app.

I am trying to build project on my machine which working fine in other machine but it throws error on my local machine during build process. Please check following is error details.

```
D:\Projects\Mindport\Android_1.0.0>ionic platform update android
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Updating android project...
Android project updated with cordova-android@5.1.1
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\Projects\Mindport\Android_1.0.0\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\Projects\Mindport\Android_1.0.0
add to body class: platform-android

D:\Projects\Mindport\Android_1.0.0>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\Projects\Mindport\Android_1.0.0\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\Projects\Mindport\Android_1.0.0
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Keval\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_60
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132311Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareMeLeolinShortcutBadger112Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Action;
 FAILED
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)



BUILD FAILED

Total time: 27.198 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"D:\Projects\Mindport\Android_1.0.0\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Projects\Mindport\Android_1.0.0\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found issue, the development android API is 18 and I have not installed android sdk and API 18.

I just install SDK and API of 18 and its work fine.

Thanks.